# Dictionary to XML

Tags: c#, xml, linq, dictionary

So,  I have the following function that takes in a Dictionary of Users and ControlNumbers and outputs it to XML. Found some LINQ online that did this very well; but I have one small problem.

```
    static Dictionary<string, User> UserClassDict = new Dictionary<string, User>();
     static void DictionaryToXML(Dictionary<string,User> UserClassDict)
        {
            XElement el = new XElement("root", UserClassDict.Select(kv => new XElement(kv.Key, kv.Value.ControlNumber

)));
        }
```

The XML looks like this:

```
    <root>
  <adolan>792365</adolan>
  <afeazell>791964</afeazell>
  <amsmith>790848</amsmith>
  <asnyder>790948789358</asnyder>
</root>
```

But as you can see, the ControlNumbers are generally 6 digits long (HOWEVER this is not always the case). What I would like to happen is something similar to this.

```
    <root>
<adolan>
<controlNumbers>123456</controlNumbers>
 </adolan>
<asnyder>
<controlNumbers>222111</controlNumbers>
<controlNumbers>333222</controlNumbers>
</asnyder>
</root>
```

Eventually I will have the program read this XML file at start up and populate the Dictionary so this XML will eventually get pretty large. Any ideas would be helpful.

Comment: When a user has two or more controlNumbers, how is it represented in the dictionary?

Comment: The ControlNumbers are saved into a List<int> inside the USER class. So, if I understand your question, they are saved inside a List that is located inside the User Class.

Comment: Side note: your XML schema is sub-optimal (or simply bad): using user names as node names will give you a lot of pain down the road (O`Something ot non ASCII names...) - consider attribute instead, serializing lists into comma separated string is not convenient as you have to parse data essentially twice - once as XML, second as string - sequence of of elements may be better.

Comment: @MaylorTaylor, so does your `ControlNumber` property just concatenate the contents of that list?

Comment: @SamIam it shouldn't. I would like each controlNumber to be in it's own node inside the parent node for the user. That way I can easily import the data back into the program.

Comment: BTW you can use the .NET's built-in [DataContract](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733127.aspx) stuff, which also supports Json

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
XElement el = new XElement("root",
      UserClassDict.Select(kv => new XElement(kv.Key, 
       kv.Value.ControlNumbers.Select(num => new XElement("controlNumbers", num))))
);
```

Comment: PERFECT! Thank you! I really need to read this LINQ book I have haha

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand how 2 or more control numbers are represented in your dictionary, but if you want to do some more complex xlm generation, you can change your lambda so that it invokes a method.

```
kv => new XElement(kv.Key, kv.Value.ControlNumber)
```

would change to

```
kv => BuildXMLElement(kv)
```

and you can implement `BuildXMLElement` to build the element as you like

Answer (score 0):

Change your el to

```
 XElement el = new XElement("root", UserClassDict.
            Select(kv => new XElement(kv.Key, 
                from it in kv.Value.ControlNumber
                select new XElement("controlNumbers", it)
                )));
```

The above LINQ query will create multiple controlNumbers tags

To concatenate, use

```
XElement el = new XElement("root", UserClassDict.
            Select(kv => new XElement(kv.Key, 
                String.Join(",", kv.Value.ControlNumber.ToArray())
                )));
```